# How to SELECT LIKE from SQL without duplicate viewing id

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

I am using this code :

```
<?
$i_count=1;

$sSQL         = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status=1 AND location LIKE '%" . $a_project[0]["location"] . "%' ORDER BY delivery_year DESC, project_id DESC LIMIT 0,5";
$mysql_result = mysql_query($sSQL, $GLOBALS['conn']);
$num_rows     = mysql_num_rows($mysql_result);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
?>
<br />
```

It will show the project with same location with viewing project. But it also show the current project in the result. 
Ex : I have 02 projects in location Hanoi name A and B. When I view project A, the related projects show both A and B project.

How I can fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: Add a new where clause telling mysql not to pick the current id

Comment: Your condition needs an expression to filter by project id or whatever makes your projects unique. By the way you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection,  see [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html ).

Comment: I add project_id <> " . $a_project[0]["project_id"] . "  and look like it works. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the current project in the WHERE:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status=1 AND location LIKE '%" . $a_project[0]["location"] . "%' AND id <> " . $a_project[0]["id"] . " ORDER BY delivery_year DESC, project_id DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

(Or something like it, depending on your field names and such)